# Event name when select an option inside a select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know the event name when we change something in a select is `change` (html: `onchange`), but I would like to know what is the event name when I select (click) a specific option.

Example :

```
<select>
    <option>Option 1</option>
</select>
```

When I click on `Option 1`, what event happen ? Only `change` (on the select itself and all option) or something else ?

Thanks.

Comment: In most browsers change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, in most browser happen `change` event when you change `select` and `click` event for `option`.

```
$('select').on('change', function(event) {
  console.log(event.type);   // event.type is to get event name
});
```

Answer (score 2):

'change' on the SELECT and 'click' on the OPTION. Also, in Opera, 'input' might fire on the SELECT too if you add the listener with addEventListener() for example.

Comment: Though the chosen answer shows how to look it up yourself, which is VERY useful, this is, actually, the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

event.type returns the nature of event. Refer the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gFdkF/1/)

```
$('select').bind('change', function(event) {
    alert("Event :"+ event.type);   
});
```

You can use .on/.bind on the element.​

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in the onclick event of the option you are interested in like so:

```
<select id="MySelect">
    <option id="optionA" onclick="alert('You clicked A')">a</option>
    <option id="optionB">b</option>  
</select>
```